# Equivalence of three versions of search operation over binary tree (not BST)

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have the following three version of the search operation over the binary tree (not ordering).

Given:

```
type 'a btree = 
| Empty
| Node of 'a * 'a btree * 'a btree;;
```

I have:

1.

```
let rec bsearch x tree = 
  match tree with 
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node (root, left, right) -> 
      if (root = x) then tree else
        match left with 
        | Empty -> bsearch x right
        | Node (_, left, _) -> bsearch x left;;
```

2. 

```
let rec bsearch x tree = 
  match tree with 
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node (root, left, right) when x = root -> tree
  | Node (_, left, right) ->
    match left with
    | Empty -> bsearch x right
    | t -> bsearch x t;;
```

3. 

```
let rec bsearch x t =
  match t with
  | Empty -> Empty
  | Node(a, left, right) ->
      if a = x then t
      else 
        match bsearch x left with
        | Empty -> bsearch x right
        | t' -> t'
```

Assuming these are equivalent, having the same time complexity, and except the last one not being tail recursive, what is the big difference between them? I also find the last line in 3.:

```
| t' -> t'
```

to never be used. Is it correct that the last one is the least efficient of all three versions.

Answer (score 0):

### Function 1

If the node does not contain the value we're looking for, then we check to see if the left branch is `Empty`. If it is, we search the right branch. That makes sense.

If it's *not* though, then we immediately search the left branch node's left branch. We've skipped a node.

Let's consider a very simple tree. No right branches at all.

```
     --5
    /
  -3
 /
1
```

If we're searching for `3`, then this considers `5` and finds it doesn't equal `3`. The left branch isn't `Empty` but rather `Node (3, Node (1, Empty, Empty), Empty)` so it evaluates `bsearch 3 (Node (1, Empty, Empty), Empty))`.  This node isn't `Empty`, the value doesn't match, but the left branch is `Empty`, so we search the right branch. The right branch is `Empty`, so the result is `Empty`.

### Function 2

What happens here if the value we're looking for isn't found in the left branch? Consider again a sample tree.

```
        -----5-----
       /           \
   ---3---       ---7---
  /       \     /       \
 2         4   6         8
```

We search for `6`. We should get `Node (6, Empty, Empty)`.

`5` isn't right, and the left branch isn't `Empty`, so we search it.

`3` isn't right, and the left branch isn't `Empty`, so we search it.

`2` isn't right, but the left branch is `Empty`, so we search the right branch. That's `Empty` too, so the result is `Empty`.

### Function 3

Let's rerun that last example tree search with this function.

`5` isn't right, so we search the left branch.

`3` isn't right, so we search the left branch.

`2` isn't right, so we search the left branch.

The left branch is `Empty` so we get `Empty` back. Because that returned `Empty` we search the right branch. The right branch is `Empty` so we get `Empty` back.

We now search the right branch of `Node (3, Node (2, Empty, Empty), Node (4, Empty, Empty))`. We know this will return `Empty` and we'll end up searching `Node (7, Node (6, Empty, Empty), Node (8, Empty, Empty))`.

`7` isn't right, so we search the left branch.

`6` *is* correct, so we return `Node (6, Empty, Empty)`.

### Summary

Function 3 is correct, and has a time complexity of O(n). The time complexities of the other two functions are somewhat moot as they do not return correct results.

In function 3, that last line `| t' -> t'` is used when `bsearch x left` returns a `Node` rather than `Empty`.

As noted in a previous answer on this subject, a "worklist" based approach to this problem, where right branches are added to a list of nodes to process not only handles searching the entire tree (in a depth-first manner), but eliminates the tail-recursion.

```
let search x t =
  let rec search' x t stack =
    match t, stack with
    | Empty, [] -> Empty
    | Empty, n::ns -> search' x n ns
    | Node (v, _, _), _ when x = v -> t
    | Node (_, l, r), _ -> search' x l @@ r :: stack
  in
  search' x t []
```